# Bolt CMS access Bolt\Twig\TwigExtension from twig file

Tags: twig, bolt-cms

I try to use `localdatetime` in my template twig file, but I get an error that `localdatetime` does not exists:

`Unknown "localizeddate" filter. Did you mean "localdate" in "listing.twig" at line 51?`

However when I look into the code, the TwigExtension class is already there and defines the `localdatetime` Twig_SimpleFilter too.

So I cannot see why I cannot use them in the code. Do someone know whats going on?

This is my twig template code:
`{{ record.datepublish | localizeddate('full', 'none', app.request.locale ) }}`

Answer (score 0):

Use `localedatetime` instead of `localizeddate` or `localdatetime`.